# Excel - Conversion of date to English text string

Tags: excel

I am aware of the characteristic whereby VBA always treats dates as being in the US mm/dd/yyyy format but do not know how to get around this for my particular problem. I wish to end up with the date as a text string with dots as the separaters and in the UK style (i.e. dd.mm.yyyy) to enable data input by another program. I currently have:

```
`Range("F2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Replace What:="/", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

(the first lines are pasting the data into the sheet I'll be using for the data input)

but of course, these end up as mm.dd.yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Range("A1") = Now
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="/", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date you have to put in the worksheet comes from a calculation you can try this snippet:

```
Dim mydate As Date
mydate = Now()
Range("F2") = Format(mydate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
```